# Angular ngInfiniteScroll not scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to "refactor" an example provided by the author of the ngInfiniteScroll in a not-OOP way. (http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html#)
Something is totally wrong in my code because the scrolling is not triggered. 
A fix and explanation would be really appreciated.

This is my plunker code:  http://plnkr.co/edit/hFHKhOvokL4ywGERExew?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my controller, I was binding $scope.nextPage to the return value of the fetchServer service. Instead,I had to call the fetchServer function each time the page is scrolled, so $scope.nextPage should be a function:

```
$scope.nextPage = function() {
  fetchServer(function(items){
    $scope.items=items;
  })
};
```

Here’s the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nKFrVoxjOB8JLqnis87B?p=preview